# Collection Anidados Backbone

Tags: jquery, underscorejs, backbone

solicito de su ayuda para que me ayuden a obtener el valor de una llave que se encuentra anidada, cuando renderizo, me muestra el primer nivel pero no se como llegar al los nodos mas internos, el modelo es:

```
{
 "ciudadDepartamento": "Bogotá",
 "estadoDepartamento": true,
 "fechaCreacion": "2016-05-12T00:00:00-05:00",
 "id": 1,
 "idFacultad": {
  "ciudadFacultad": "Bogotá",
  "estadoFacultad": true,
  "fechaCreacion": "2016-05-12T00:00:00-05:00",
  "id": 2,
  "nombreFacultad": "Facultad de Ingeniería y Ciencias Básicas"
 },
 "nombreDepartamento": "Ciencias básicas"
}
```

quiero obtener el valor de nombreFacultad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[VER DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/go4vz3L1/4/)**

```
var JsonGetData = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function (data) {       
        return data.idFacultad;
    }
});

var JsonGetDataResult = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: JsonGetData
});

var j = new JsonGetDataResult([{

 "ciudadDepartamento": "Bogotá",
 "estadoDepartamento": true,
 "fechaCreacion": "2016-05-12T00:00:00-05:00",
 "id": 1,
 "idFacultad": {
  "ciudadFacultad": "Bogotá",
  "estadoFacultad": true,
  "fechaCreacion": "2016-05-12T00:00:00-05:00",
  "id": 2,
  "nombreFacultad": "Facultad de Ingeniería y Ciencias Básicas"
 },
 "nombreDepartamento": "Ciencias básicas"
}], { parse: true });

/* Mira en tu consola */
console.log(j.first().get('nombreFacultad'));
// salida: Facultad de Ingeniería y Ciencias Básicas
```

No he tratado aún **backbone.js** pero me he informado un poco de la [API-Integration](http://backbonejs.org/#API-integration) y espero que esto es lo que buscabas.

Comment: super genial, mil gracias